# integrate outlook mail to my website

Tags: jakarta-ee, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, outlook-2010

I have a J2EE website that offers *Software-As-A-Service* services for my users. I want to use the outlook mail exchange server, to be used by my users. Therefore, I want to:

First, Embed the outlook mail in my website using an IFrame.
 Then, Synchronize the outlook users to my users. (Each user using my service, can have an outlook account through my website)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly is your question here? Do you want both?

Comment: Yes please, I want to do both.

Answer (score 0):

When setting up exchange server you should be able to integrate it with IIS and setup OWA for email services delivered through your web server, like:

```
Https://Mysite.com/owa
```

Then use that domain in your iframe.
Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Exchange 2010, you can use the Outlook WebApp webparts: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232199.aspx

I still have trouble understanding what your goal is with your second step. Do you want to replicate the mails from Exchange to your system?

Comment: Thanks a lot Krause for your link..

I want the users on my system to be able to use outlook as their mail server..